# Safari CSS bug?

Tags: css, safari

I asked this question earlier, and someone posted something on Fiddle showing that my code should indeed work with Safari. So I stripped down my page, trying to find any bugs. In fact, I did find a rather significant but - but it didn't fix my problem.

The problem is that elements (e.g. headers) assigned a high z-index value do not float above an element with a lower z-index value.

I created a new page with very simple HTML and tried it, with the same results. Yet the same code works perfectly in JFiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/eono6z69/

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
 background: #cff;
}
.test {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 5;
}
h2 {
 color: #00f;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1000;
}
```

Since the code obviously works, there must be a bug in my browser. I cleared my cache (history), but that didn't fix anything. I upgraded to Yosemite and Safari 8.0 fairly recently, so this is apparently some weird but that hasn't really been fixed yet.

I just wondered if anyone might have experienced something similar. I fixed it earlier by modifying my z-index scheme - but the new scheme doesn't work with other browsers.

Nevertheless, that would be a solution, if there's a way to write a style sheet that only works for a particular browser (Safari). Can that be done?

Comment: Please do NOT post a jsFiddle URL as a code block.  Links should be clickable.

Comment: The "bug" can't be in _your_ Safari 8 if the jsFiddle works fine in everyone else's Safari 8.

Comment: Where else could it be? The HTML is obviously fine, so the bug has to be outside the code. That pretty much leaves my Safari installation, unless my laptop itself somehow causes the problem. And, like I said, I fixed the problem earlier by modifying my CSS styles.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're verifying that it DOES work in your Safari browser, then I could just forget about it. Whether or not it works in my browser is largely irrelevant if it works in other people's browsers.

Comment: It's working here in Safari 8.0.2 (Yosemite 10.10.1)

Comment: Well, that's weird, but I guess I'll just forget about it if I'm the only person with this problem. ;)

Comment: Yup, fine for me in Safari too.

Comment: I took it in to an Apple store, and a tech looked at it. He copied my file and had the same problem on his computer. He couldn't figure it out, so we just dismissed it as some obscure bug that will hopefully get fixed soon.